# Log4j not printing lower levels than WARN and creating no log files

Tags: java, log4j2

I have the following log4j2.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

## Direct log messages to file
log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.File=/logs/bbt_${current.date}.log
log4j.appender.fileout.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.fileout.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.fileout.Append=false
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.conversionPattern=%5p | %d | %m%n

# Direct log messages to terminal
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%5p | %d | %m    %n
```

and the following temporary test class

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Temp {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.error("error");
        log.debug("debug");
        log.info("info");
        log.fatal("fatal");
        log.trace("trace");
        log.warn("warn");
    }
}
```

However, when I run the test class I get the following output:

> 11:32:19.295 [main] ERROR Temp - error
>
> 11:32:19.298 [main] FATAL Temp - fatal

Additionally, no /logs/ folder or log files are created. I thought the issue with the log levels might be caused by the fact that I'm setting a treshold in the first block (for the file), but commenting out this block makes no difference. Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause here?

Comment: Can you show when you create the logger? As far as I know when you create the logger you pass the fileappender reference to it and give it a name to call with LogManager.getLogger(); Here is a tutorial I followed (in java, but should give solid advice) https://stackify.com/log4j2-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you've used a properties file from Log4J version 1, but are trying to use Log4J version 2.

This version 2 properties file, named as `log4j2.properties` on the classpath, worked for me:

```
name=PropertiesConfig

rootLogger.level=debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout, file
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=StandardOutput
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref=LogFile

appenders=console, file

## Direct log messages to file
appender.file.type=File
appender.file.name=LogFile
appender.file.fileName=logs/bbt_${current.date}.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=%5p | %d | %m%n

# Direct log messages to terminal
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=StandardOutput
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%5p | %d | %m    %n
```